# updating and existing object in firestore database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the following example I am updating 2 things. The first thing is an existing array in the db, and the second thing is an existing object. The array pushing is working as it should, but the object has an issue. I mean is there an equivalent for array union to object?

```js
   // Doc model current state before the incoming update.
   data 
   {items :[]}
   {lists : {}}
   
   
   const addObjToClientsArr = async () => {
      const docRef = doc(db, 'data', _authContext.currentUser.uid);
      const payload = selected;
      // Array
      await updateDoc(docRef, { items: arrayUnion(payload) });
      // Obeject
      const payload2 = {[context.id]: [
            { a : 1 },
          ]}
        
       updateDoc(docRef, {
        lists: {
         payload2
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to [update a field inside a nested object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects), which you can do with:

```
const path = `lists.${context.id}.a`;
await updateDoc(docRef, {
  [path]: 1
})
```

Comment: I updated the question to explain the flow better sorry my bad